# Rename several gopro files

Tags: bash, sh, spring-batch

I have video files with this structure : `GX**####` where `####` is the number of the video.
But sometimes videos are splitted in 2 or 3 files, for instance : `GX01####` and `GX02####`
My problem is that to organise my folders I prefer rename them like this : `GX####-1` and `GX####-2`.

So i ask you the question if I can create a script/command to rename automatically my files to do this ? I can use .bat windows files or .sh linux files. My main problem is that i don't know a command to rename files simply (i saw many solutions which rewrite the entire file). May be if you know just this I will can do my script.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Yes you can.  `mv` renames files.  You can use `find` to loop on the files, or use a list of the files you want to rename.  `sed` or `awk` can be used to "calculate" the new filename you want. Using bash on linux is simpler than a bat file (IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the files and use PE parameter expansion to slice and jumble the strings and mv to rename the files.

Here is an example, first let us create an empty files using touch, but first we need to create a new directory (folder as you call it) and go into that newly created directory, using mkdir and cd.

```
mkdir newdirectory && cd newdirectory
```

Now create the empty files using touch.

```
touch GX01#### GX02#### GX03#### GX04####
```

Now check the empty files using ls

```
ls *
```

The output should be like

```
GX01####  GX02####  GX03####  GX04####
```

Now that we have created empty files, we can now do the renaming part.

```
for file in GX*; do
  file1="${file#*??}"
  file2=${file1#*??}
  file3=${file1%*$file2}
  echo mv -v "$file" "${file%*$file1}${file2}"-"$file3"
done
```

The output should be on stdout (which is your screen) because of the echo.

```
mv -v GX01#### GX####-01
mv -v GX02#### GX####-02
mv -v GX03#### GX####-03
mv -v GX04#### GX####-04
```

If you're satisfied with what you see then remove the **echo**, so mv can actually rename the files. To show how the slicing is done here is an example.

```
file=GX01####
file1="${file#*??}"
file2=${file1#*??}
file3="${file1%*$file2}"
printf '%s\n' "$file1" "$file2" "$file3"
```

The output should be something like.

```
01####
####
01
```

The **?** means a single string from the shell.

A word of caution and advice, make a backup of the files you want to edit just in case the shell made a mistake while you're renaming the files. :-)

Also you should probably use shell globing like **nullglob**  see

[http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

See man bash and look for Parameter Expansion.

```
PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*parameter\ expansion' man bash
```

Some online resources, with detailed explanation and examples.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Good solution, well explained. I mark the subject as resolved. I just use in addition dos2unix after edit it to run it on my windows with linux shell. I will just change your code to place the extension at the good place.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You could echo the original and new file names:

```sh
for f in GX*; do
    echo "$f" $(sed 's/^GX\(..\)\(.*\)/GX\2-\1/' <<< "$f")
done
```

which should output:

```
GX01#### GX####-01
GX02#### GX####-02
```

then use `mv -n` instead of `echo` to rename the files.

Comment: Really elegant solution, but what is the purpose of the instruction `<<<` ? Is that a rewrite of the file or just part of the string operation ?

Comment: The `<<<` is called a *here-string*, you can read about it in [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)