# bash script to rearrange multiple file names correctly(go pro)

Tags: bash

I have multiple GoPro files in a directory that all need to be renamed and would like a bash script to do it.  Basically I want to move the 3rd and 4th characters back to the 12th and 13th spot with dashes around it.  The only other GoPro post I found puts it at the end of the file but I really need it in the middle like that.  Thank you

**Example**

Original filename is:

GX010112_1647792633961.MP4

and I need it to look like:

GX0112_164-01-7792633961.MP4

Comment: Do this with the `rename` command.

Comment: Hey, a bit off-topic, but how did you get the UTC timestamp in the filename? I really need this for my project with GoPro

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer with the **rename** command-line. It allows you to rename multiple files according to PERL regex.

```
#installation of rename
apt install rename

#rename your files
rename 's/^(.{2})(.{2})(.{8})(.*)/$1$3-$2-$4/' *
```

**REGEX explanation:**

The regex is structured as s/ MATCHING PATTERN / REPLACEMENT /

^: set position at the beginning of string.

(.{2}) : Match the first 2 characters and store it in $1.

(.{2}) : Match the following 2 characters (the 3th and 4th) and store it in $2.

(.{8}) : Match the following 8 characters (from the 5th to 12th included) and store it in $3.

(.*) : Match the rest of you string and store it in $4.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahhh thanks!  I figured something else out based on a similar thread

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I figured it out based on this thread:
[Rename several gopro files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708360/rename-several-gopro-files)

```
for file in GX*; do
  file1="${file#*??}"
  file2=${file1#*??}
  file3=${file1#*??????}
  file4=${file1%*$file2}
  file5=${file2%*?????????????????}
  mv -v "$file" "${file5}${file4}${file3}"
done
```

I hope it comes in handy for any other GoProers out there!